# How to dismiss popup window in Array Adapter class in Android

Tags: android

I'm creating popup window and open the popup window on ListView item click event.There are two buttons in popup window , one is btnCamera and another is btnDismiss.The problem is when i capture the image and back to the listview at that time popup window does not get cancel automatically.I tried to cancel the popup window onResume() method in Activity.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
 if(adapter.popupWindow_Camera != null)
        {
            adapter.popupWindow_Camera.dismiss();
            adapter.popupWindow_Camera = null;
        }

    }
```

And here is my popup window on ListView item click .

```
    holder.imgBtn_Camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_popup, (ViewGroup) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
                        popupWindow_Camera = new PopupWindow(popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        popupWindow_Camera.setWidth(720);
                        popupWindow_Camera.setHeight(350);
                        popupWindow_Camera.setFocusable(true);
                        popupWindow_Camera.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 87);
                        popupWindow_Camera.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

                        Button btnCamera = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.button_Camera);
                        Button btnGallery = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.button_Gallery);
                        Button btnDismiss = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelCamera);

                        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)
 {
                              Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "classnkk_images";
                            File myPath = new File(extr, picformat);
                            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(myPath));
                            ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                            Log.e("Camera", " Open");
                            popupWindow_Camera.dismiss();  
                            }
                        });

                        btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                popupWindow_Camera.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

                        popupWindow_Camera.showAsDropDown(holder.imgBtn_Camera, 50, -30);
                    }
                });
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue.Thanks .

Comment: On button camera on click you should dismiss your pop-up window

Comment: do you capture image in a different activity and come back to the activity with list view? 
If yes, then you should consider `startActivityOnResult` and get capture result back in method `onActivityResult` in activity with list view

Comment: My question is after capturing the image and back to ListView activity  how to dismiss popup window automatically .And i have already done for getting the images from camera.

Comment: @Vivek Mishra : i tried dismiss pop-up window on camera button . but issue of application is immediately close and open and popup window is close.

Comment: Did you try dismissing pop-up after calling camera intent??

Comment: Yes , i tried but application is immediately close and open itself .

Answer (score 0):

//While you are intended for startActivityOnResult(), than after completion of your camera operation onActivityResult() method will be called... So you should try this " popupWindow_Camera.dismiss(); " within your onResultActivity().

Comment: See my edited  post .In camera button i tried to dismiss the popup window.

Comment: have you called onActivityResult(){}

Comment: Yes , but i have called onActivityResult(){}  in Main Activity and i have create  AllPostAdapter class is a separate class .

Comment: try with popupwindow.cancel();

Comment: I don't found any cancel(); method for popupwindow.

Comment: Now you have to check whether popupwindow.dismiss() is working or not...? for that comment your btnCamera.setOnClickListener{} code except  popupwindow.dismiss();

Comment: popupwindow.dismiss() is working but why to close application and open again itself after getting the images from camera and then popupwindow.dismiss(); .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100208/discussion-between-p-ld-and-fatehali-asamadi).